# Microsoft Windows 64-bit application development best practises installation folder

Tags: windows, 64-bit

My problem is that a vendor is providing me with a 64bit application (packed in a 64bit installer) but it goes and installs to the x86 (Program Files) Folder and he keeps telling me its OK but I want it to install in the Program Files directory; as the 32 bit version does that and scripts for the app are developed based on this assumption.

Can someone direct me to the Microsoft recommended best practices for 64bit applications(links).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

About Windows Installer on 64-Bit Operating Systems
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367451.aspx

Is your vendor installing the app via an MSI file? If so, their app setup generator (WIX, InstallShield, etc) should be creating MSI's that store their components in the correct places.

If not and they're installing using a custom script, suggest they start investing in learning WIX ;)

Either way, they should be following the recommended guidelines and installing 64-bit code and 32-bit code to the correct locations and modifying the correct registry trees accordingly.